# What religious order do these nuns belong to?

Tags: catholicism, religious-orders, clothing

The habit of these nuns includes no guimpe (or a black one), a black veil, a white wimple, a rectangular white coif:

[image: picture taken in 1963]

Which order do they belong to?

(I couldn't find anything quite like it on [NunsAndSisters.com](http://www.nunsandsisters.com/Photographs.html).)

Comment: Nun of the above, of course :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are of the Sisters of Charity of St. Elizabeth ([source](https://www.fisheaters.com/forums/index.php?topic=3466086.msg33984535#msg33984535)).

Comment: Here is [a clearer image](http://www.scnj.org/images/SMT%20sepia.JPG) from their [site](http://www.scnj.org/).

Comment: I originally posted " a clearer image from their [site](http://www.scnj.org/)". The photo has disappeared, but archived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150919231516/http://www.scnj.org/images/SMT%20sepia.JPG) .